# Print values of dictionary one by one

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a function that has to "loop" through my dictionary. The content of the dictionary contains 4 questions that I want to ask my user, one by one.
Starting with the first question, I want to ask all the questions that I have in my dictionary. When all the questions are asked, I want my function to stop. I tried to search for the answer that I am seeking for, but unfortunately without any results..
I have also created a diagram, that explains the algorithm that I want to write. See the link below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNWUq.png

The code that I have:

```
import random
from time import sleep

def vragenLijst():
    vragen_list = open("questions.txt").readlines()
    return vragen_list
 

def stel_vraag(vragen_list):
    vragen_IAT = {
        "vraag_1" : str(vragen_list[0]),
        "vraag_2" : str(vragen_list[1]),
        "vraag_3" : str(vragen_list[2]),
        "vraag_4" : str(vragen_list[3])
    }
    vragen_FICT = {
        "vraag_5" : vragen_list[4],
        "vraag_6" : vragen_list[5],
        "vraag_7" : vragen_list[6],
        "vraag_8" : vragen_list[7]
    }
    vragen_SE = {
        "vraag_9" : vragen_list[8],
        "vraag_10" : vragen_list[9],
        "vraag_11" : vragen_list[10],
        "vraag_12" : vragen_list[11]
    }
    vragen_BDAM = {
        "vraag_13" : vragen_list[12],
        "vraag_14" : vragen_list[13],
        "vraag_15" : vragen_list[14],
        "vraag_16" : vragen_list[15]
    }

    counter_IAT = 0
    print("Hier komen de eerste vragen: ")
    sleep (2.0)

    print()
    while vragen_IAT:
        antwoord = input(vragen_IAT + "Y/N: ")
        for vragen in vragen_IAT:
            if antwoord == "y" or antwoord == "Y":
                counter_IAT = counter_IAT + 1
                print(counter_IAT)

            elif antwoord == "n" or antwoord == "N":
                counter_IAT = counter_IAT
                print(counter_IAT)
                
            else: 
                print("Dit heb ik niet begrepen.. Vul [Y]es of [N]o in: ")
                if antwoord != "y" or antwoord != "Y":
                    continue

    
    # while vragen_FICT:



    # while vragen_SE: 


    # while vragen_BDAM:

    

def main():
    vragen = vragenLijst()
    stel_vraag(vragen)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am new and I hope that I explained my question good enough for you guys! All the help will be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Your ``vragen_list`` is already a list with all questions. What's the advantage of putting them in dictionaries before you display them to the user?
you could just group them by index (IAT = [0,1,2,3]; FICT = [4,5,6,7] ...)

Comment: An array of questions seems more reasonable to use here than a dictionary unless this is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your whole code, but give you a background. Assume `myDict` as the dictionary of your questions, so you can iterate over the keys which are the questions, and validate with `if` like this:

```
for question in myDict.keys():
  myAnswer = input(question)
  if myAnswer # Continue validation
```

Comment: Hey man! I have used your explanation, it works for me! I just have to research how to stop after 4 questions now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for what you are asking:

```
questions = {'alpha? ': 'y', 'beta? ': 'n'}

for q,a in questions.items():
    while input(q).lower() != a:
        print("WRONG!")
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment! I have used the for loop and then my if statement with my own validations that I have.